# random quote generator with php, ajax and mysql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i've tried using [this code](http://www.carteblanchegroup.com/2008/04/14/phpmysqlajax-random-quote/) and [this](http://www.ddrewdesign.com/blog/index.php?cmd=article&id=86) to make a random quote generator, but it doesn't display anything. my questions are:

- what is wrong with my code?
- in the above tut, the quote is generated on a button click, i'd like
  a random quote to be displayed every
  30 mins automatically. how do i do
  this?

////////////////////////

quote.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>

<!–create the div for the quotes land–>
<div id="quote"><strong>this</strong></div>
<div><a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="run_query();">Next quote …</a></div>

</body>
</html>
```

/////////////////////

quote.php:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

// 'text' is the name of your table that contains
// the information you want to pull from
$rowcount = mysql_query("select count(*) as rows from quotes");

// Gets the total number of items pulled from database.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rowcount))
{
 $max = $row["rows"];
}

// Selects an item's index at random 
$rand = rand(1,$max)-1;
$result = mysql_query("select * from quotes limit $rand, 1");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$randomOutput = $row['storedText'];

echo '<p>' . $randomOutput . '</p>';
```

////////////

ajax.js:

```
var xmlHttp


function run_query() {
xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlHttp==null) {
alert ("This browser does not support HTTP Request");
return;
} // end if
var url="quote.php";
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
} //end function

function stateChanged(){
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){
document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
} //end if
} //end function

function GetXmlHttpObject() {
var xmlHttp=null;
try {
// For these browsers: Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}catch (e){
//For Internet Explorer
try{
xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e) {
xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
}
return xmlHttp;
} //end function
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, the "quote.php" file could be simplified to 
`select * from quotes limit 1 order by rand()`

Comment: Hey! Just a suggestion: You can do this with a JavaScript array to simplify things. MySQL is great, but it's a little bit much for displaying such a small amount of data. Also, onClick is a little old school, I'd recommend giving jQuery a try, the handlers and CSS based naming system are miracles.

Comment: i tried that. doesn't display anything.

Comment: kyle, can you give me an example? the quotes database which i have in mysql is not a small amount of data and i wouldn't want to manually type in 100 quotes in the javascript array. . any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to print the values for $max,$rand and $result. You can use print_r to get more info from the php page.

Run the quote.php on browser to see if you get an output. 
Then get to ajax to debug.

You can use a timer in ajax to automate your requests for every 30 mins or so. use javascript's settimeout function for this.

HTH

Comment: i ran quote.php on the browser, but i get no input. is something wrong with my php code?

Comment: Is there any data to begin with? I think you need to debug to figure out whats happening.