# How can I make a random quote generator with ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, random

Basically I have a page with a quote in it. Underneath the quote, I will have a link that will be clicked and the quote will be updated with an ajax call from the database to display the new content. I can do it with a regular php file, but I wanted to add some ajax into the mix so that the entire page isn't refreshed each time.

Can someone explain how to do this? I scoped out [random quote generator with php, ajax and mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593090/random-quote-generator-with-php-ajax-and-mysql) but the code given was giving me issues.

Comment: what issues was it giving you exactly?

Comment: yeah, this question is too hazy to be answered well

Comment: Go to http://www.w3schools.com and study their tutorial on PHP (specifically the MySQL chapter) then check out jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're confused by ajax in that article.
Try using jQuery's ajax like so:

```
$.ajax({
   'type': 'POST'
   'url' : 'yourfile.php',
   'success': function(data){
      $('#yourquote').html(data);
   }
});
```

That is all there is to it, provided yourfile.php returns just a random string representing your quote. Also - 'yourquote' is the id of the div or whatever you used to store your quote in.

Tell me if this helps.